# How do I get the text next to a checkbox to wrap around?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, element-ui

I have these checkboxes on my website. Formatted as below

```
<el-row>
  <div class="sentbox" align="left" :style="{display: sentence1 === '' ? 'none' : 'block'}">
    <el-checkbox v-model="sent1"> {{sentence1}} </el-checkbox>
  </div>
</el-row>
```

CSS for sentbox is just:

```
.sentbox {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

But what ends up happening is the sentence might be too long and goes past width of the screen forcing the user to scroll to right to see the entire sentence. As you may see in the picture below, the sentence is cut off and I would have to scroll to the right. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Example of how it looks is below]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `el-checkbox` from Element UI sets a `white-space:nowrap` style, but you could apply `white-space:initial` to allow the text to wrap:

```css
.el-checkbox {
  white-space: initial;
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rNjLeoG?editors=1100)